# How many wives did Yudhishthira have?

Tags: mahabharata, yudhisthira

It is well known that Draupadi is wife of Yudhishthira.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yudhishthira) and several other sources say that there is another wife to him and her name is Devika. The following [excerpt](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01096.htm) from Chapter 95, Sambhava Parva, Mahabharata clarifies it.

> Besides these, Yudhishthira, having obtained for his wife **Devika, the daughter of Govasana of the Saivya tribe**, in a self-choice ceremony, begat upon her a son named Yaudheya.

My doubt : Are there any other wives for him other than these two and are there any more references to Devika in any scriptures other than that provided in Mahabharata?

Answer (score 8):

Currently, I am answering only this part: **Are there any other wives for him other than these two?**

According to [Shrimad Bhagavatam, 9.22.30-31](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/22/30-31), Pauravi is another wife of Yudhishthira.

> O King, the son of Sahadeva was Śrutakarmā. Furthermore, Yudhiṣṭhira and his brothers begot other sons in other wives. **Yudhiṣṭhira begot a son named Devaka through the womb of Pauravī**, and Bhīmasena begot a son named Ghaṭotkaca through his wife Hiḍimbā and a son named Sarvagata through his wife Kālī. Similarly, Sahadeva had a son named Suhotra through his wife named Vijayā, who was the daughter of the king of the mountains.